# How to fix this error in my android manifest, flutter project, Android studio

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, android-manifest, manifest

I have a bug in my android manifest it showing "Attribute tools:replace is not allowed here, Unresolved class 'MainActivity' "
and if I run the app I got this bug
Class 'String' has no instance method '>'.
Receiver: "0.00"
Tried calling: >(0)
[mainactivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZliD.jpg)

This is my manifest code

`

```
<application
        android:label="AEMC Academy"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
        <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!--FOR STRIPE-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                    android:scheme="com.aemcacademy"
                    android:host="3ds.stripesdk.io" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!--END FOR STRIPE-->
    </activity>

    <activity
            android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
            android:value="true" />

    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
</application>
```

`

[This is the error that i have in manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oP7z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The namespace declaration for tools could be missing from the manifest header.

This solution worked for me:
Add xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" just below <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: i already have it

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of the Class with a String type.

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="com.aemcacademy">

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZliD.jpg this is the mainactivity

Comment: @AlhassanAbubakarSadiq did you find any solution?